# Javascript interface in pygtk interface?

Tags: javascript, webkit, pygtk

Android lets you add a Javascript Interface, that will let you use "window.interfacename.myfunction()" to call a function in the Java program.

Is there any similar feature that allows a PyGTK with embedded webkit browser to have similar functionality, to call a specific Python function from Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a handler for special urls. I overrode the webkit with:

```
webview.connect("navigation-policy-decision-requested", self.webkitGo)
```

where self.webkitGo is the name of the function: `def webkitGo(self, view, frame, net_req, nav_act, pol_dec):`

In this function, you can receive the url data from `net_req.get_uri()` and decide what to do with it, and [return true to not do the default behavior](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-navigation-policy-decision-requested).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in C using the JavaScriptCore library that comes with WebKit. I don't know any examples in PyGTK, but I assume that JavaScriptCore is available through GObject Introspection.

Comment: It looks like there is a Python module to access JS from Python, but not the other way round: http://eikke.com/tag/javascriptcore/

Comment: try `from gi.repository import JSCore` in Python?